# DrawString with character wrapping

Tags: c#, word-wrap, drawstring

I'm creating a fatal error dialog for a Windows Mobile Application using C#. The problem is when I try to draw the stacktrace using `DrawString`, half of my stacktrace is getting clipped off because `DrawString` uses word wrapping instead of character wrapping.

For those who don't understand the explanation:

*When i draw the stacktrace, it comes out as this:*

```
at
company.application.name.space.Funct
at
company.application.name.Function(St
at
etc. etc.
```

*And i want it to print like this:*

```
at
company.application.name.space.Funct
ion(String sometext, Int32 somenumbe
r)
at
company.application.name.Function(St
ring sometext, Int32 somenumber, Int
32 anothernumber)
at
etc. etc.
```

Is this possible in Csharp?

**Reproducing the issue:**

1. Create a new smart device project. (Device application)
2. Replace the Form1 code with the following:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      RectangleF _rect = new RectangleF();
      String _stackTrace = @"at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveNoCheck(Byte[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 request, SocketFlags socketFlags)
      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsyncRequest.doRequest()
      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AsyncRequest.handleRequest()
      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.WorkerThread.doWork()
      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.WorkerThread.doWorkI(Object o)
      at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
      at System.Threading.Timer.ring()";

      protected override void ScaleControl(SizeF factor, BoundsSpecified specified)
      {
         _rect.X = 24 * factor.Width;
         _rect.Y = 10 * factor.Height;
         _rect.Width = 192 * factor.Width;
         _rect.Height = 274 * factor.Height;
      }

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      } 

      protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
      {
         base.OnPaint(e);
         using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(this.ForeColor, 1))
         {
            Rectangle borderRect = Rectangle.Round(_rect);
            borderRect.Inflate(1, 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, borderRect);
         }
         using (StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat())
         using (SolidBrush stringBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
         {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_stackTrace, this.Font, stringBrush, _rect, stringFormat);
         }
      }
   ```

   }
3. Run the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the overload of DrawString that takes a RectangleF, it should use character-wrapping.  How are you calling DrawString()?

Comment: I added code to the OP. RectangleF does not seem to solve my problem :)